# How do I get GameRanger to recognize my xCom installation?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, macos, gameranger

I've installed XCOM: Enemy Unknown on a mac, and I'm trying to configure GameRanger so I can try starting a game, see if anyone else wants to play multiplayer.

Unfortunately, GameRanger doesn't seem to recognize my XCOM installation as valid. When going to GameRanger preferences, selecting XCOM, and then searching for it on my disk, this is what I see:

[image]

No matter what I do, the file remains greyed out and I can't select it. How do I fix this issue, so I can try and play multiplayer games of XCOM?

Answer (score 2):

From [Feral Support](http://support.feralinteractive.com/en/mac-games/xcomenemyunknown/faqs/shim/):

> #### Can I play online multiplayer using GameRanger if I have the Mac App Store version of XCOM: Enemy Unknown - Elite Edition?
>
> Yes.
>
> In order to do so, you must download and install the XCOM: Enemy
> Unknown - Elite Edition GR enabler, a piece of software that enables
> players who bought XCOM: Enemy Unknown - Elite Edition from the Mac
> App Store to play online multiplayer using the GameRanger matching
> service.
>
> Players who have purchased either the DVD or downloadable version of
> XCOM: Enemy Unknown - Elite Edition do not need to install the XCOM:
> Enemy Unknown - Elite Edition GR enabler in order to play online
> multiplayer using Game Ranger.

The XCOM: Enemy Unknown - Elite Edition GR enabler can be downloaded using the following URL:

http://support.feralinteractive.com/files/xcomenemyunknown/XCOMGR.dmg

All documentation for the installation and operation of the XCOM: Enemy Unknown - Elite Edition GR enabler is included in this download.